# How to reassign eth0 from lan to wan in OpenWrt?

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have burned OpenWRT onto MR-3020 and got it working.

Unfortunately, to operate this device, I was required to connect it physically to the computer by single ethernet port called eth0.

After that I am trying to up wireless network, connect via it and then reassign eth0 to wan. All time on this way I am loosing connection to the device. The problem is that I am not understanding, what are `lan`, `eth0` and `wan`? Looks like these are entities of different classes or not?

What are rough steps of this process?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenWRT terminology:

- wan is your Internet facing interface;
- lan is your local network facing interface;
- eth0 is your first real interface.

Mind you besides having multiple interfaces, you can also assign virtual interfaces as wan or vlan.

I usually prefer having multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with exactly the same problem. To use wireless network and connect the router via eth0 to WAN, you need to set 'wan' to 'eth0' (the physical interface). You do not set any physical interface for 'lan', it will be used for the wireless network.

/etc/config/network (excerpt)

```
config interface 'lan'
  option proto 'static'
  option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
  option netmask '255.255.255.0'
 
config interface 'wan'
  option ifname 'eth0'
  option proto 'dhcp'
```

Make sure that the 'network' option for the wifi is set to "lan".

/etc/config/wireless (excerpt)

```
config wifi-iface
  option device   'radio0'
  option network  'lan'
  option mode     'ap'
  option ssid     'OpenWrt'
  option encryption 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two modes with eth0. One is **master mode** and the other one is **client mode**. If you use `option ifname 'eth0'` in `wan` interface `(/etc/config/network)` your ethernet will be in client mode. If you use that in `lan` , then ethernet will be in master mode. Also if you want wifi connection be sure to have wifi drivers in your compiled kernel/firmware of openWRT. If you don't have wifi drivers in your kernel then you can't use wireless network. In this case you must connect a ethernet cable pysically to the device.

By the way what is your AP mode specs ? Do you have the right configuration for AP mode ?

Also a useful link here . https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network